# Track user sign ups from unique link PHP

Tags: php, tracking

I am trying to track user sign ups to a website by giving each user a unique link. Each unique link however will be directed to one specific page. How do i direct that many links to one page?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a link with unique id param for example [www.example.com/usersignups?id=255](http://www.example.com/usersignups?id=255), the usersignups page will get the link id then you can do whatever tracking logic you want to implement